# Appscript Delete a Spreadsheet row after click an "Erase Link"

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I would like to insert into a spreadsheet a clicckable cell that remove a row.
In details:
I have a form. This form populates a spreadsheet and this spreadsheet is on a google site.
Now,i need to add in each row a "Remove" link so when an user click it in the google site the row is erased.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you publish a spreadsheet as a web page it looses all its spreadsheet specific features and capabilities, you can't do anything on it except viewing its content.

To get what you want you should convert the spreadsheet to an html table and insert a clickable button in every row that would call a handler that would delete the row.

This can be done with UiApp or HTML Service and, depending on the complexity of your sheet, can be simple or fairly complicated.

Below is a basic implementation of a *"spreadsheet to webapp conversion"* with a button on each row allowing for row hiding. It does not update the sheet itself but this can be added to the handler function quite easily.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('ss to Ui');
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x8buwrYsb8-HSUJ7w7MeqZAiJJIX0yC-oITBAtykBAM/edit#gid=0').getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  var grid = app.createGrid(data.length, data[0].length+1).setBorderWidth(1).setId('grid');
  var hidden = app.createHidden('hidden',data[0].length);
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('deleteRow').addCallbackElement(grid).addCallbackElement(hidden);
  for(var n in data){
    for(var i in data[0]){
      grid.setText(Number(n),Number(i),data[n][i].toString());
    }
    var button = app.createButton('x',handler).setId(n);
    grid.setWidget(Number(n),Number(i)+1,button);
  }
  var hidden = app.createHidden('hidden',data[0].length);
  app.add(grid).add(hidden);
  return app;
}

function deleteRow(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var row = Number(e.parameter.source);
  var grid = app.getElementById('grid');
  var dataW = Number(e.parameter.hidden);
  for(var n = 0;n<dataW;n++){grid.setText(row,n,'')};
  app.getElementById(row.toString()).setVisible(false);
  return app;
}
```

test [online here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyizt1_Eq6vbBoAGEQHx6X-aR1o9iTj7uYCIHNMKV3v23vlCE5Y/exec)

The spreadsheet looks like this :

[image]